# MySQL 8.0 in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Currently, I see MySQL 8.0 while creating database instance in gcloud console, but I can't find documentation (and any information about support MySQL 8 in CloudSQL).

May be anyone has information about it? Can I use this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to use MYSQL 8.0, the documentation mentioned that this was released yesterday

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/release-notes#August_25_2020